# After switching to new tab not able to locate the element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In wordpress site,I am opening a link in a new tab to add a new post, I am able to enter the post title but not able to click on publish button. I have tried all possible locators id, xpath...etc.[image: Screenshot attached]

can someone help me understand this issue. This screenshot shows page after i open link in new tab.

Here is my sample code:

```
        driver.get("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys("q1w2e3r4");
        driver.findElement(By.id("wp-submit")).click();

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10); 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='welcome-panel']/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")));         
        actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
        actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='welcome-panel']/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
        actions.keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
        actions.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

        driver.findElement(By.id("title")).sendKeys("TestPost"); //Working  
        driver.findElement(By.id("publish")).click(); //not working
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the publish box on the right an iframe?  That would cause it to not be found unless you switch into the frame.

Comment: @brendan:it's not an iframe ,  I am able to click if I don't move to a new tab.

Comment: If I open the page in main window, All elements are identified and clickable in the "publish" div section, But when I open link in new tab, I am not able to interact with any element, for some elements I am getting "element not found" exception, for publish button I am not even getting any exception, really strange!

Comment: Selenium doesn't **have the privilege to interact with the elements opened in a new tab, as the focus is always present in the initially opened tab only**. Also, **the window handle for both the tabs, is same**, hence there goes the chance of switching and interacting with elements in the newly opened tab. However, if you **open a link in a new window**, you will be able to switch the windows using window handles and interact with the elements therein.